# overlapping a scrollbar with panel "java"

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

when the mouse entered in scrollbar
automatically this scrollbar send to fond
example :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H24QN.png]

when the mouse entered in scrollbar

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3YIs.png]

thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: Your JScrollPane seems to be overlapped by another Component. But without any code snippets or any further question, only judging by your screenshots, nothing more can be said. First thing I would look into is your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setOpaque(false);
```

for the scroll bar I use the Windows 10 scroll bar

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

[image]